# How can I achieve morphing effect with Pan Gesture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to achieve the following effect with UIImageView, I already have pan gesture on an image, can anyone help me to get this effect right?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/el2l682k0g8315v/Hairstyle.mov?dl=0